# RESOLVED VisualStudio 2019 form display problem c#

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2019

I currently encountered problems with a Windows Form project I realize in C# with Visual Studio 2019.

Here is my Form :

[image: My form]

When I start the app with my screen resolution (3840x2160) everything seems ok :

[image]

But when I start the app with another screen resolution (1920x1080) there is a problem:

[image]

PictureBoxes of my CustomControl have disappear... I don't understand why ! My picutreboxes Anchor property is set to Top,Right ! And they don't stay on the right correctly..

Notice that there is no problem with the picturebox on the bottom right of my footer panel.

So the question is : why with a differnt screen resolution, pictureboxes of my customcontrol disappear ?

Thank You very much if you find any solution to this problem...

[EDIT]

> Remove the anchor and try manually placing your custom control to the desired location.

If I do that here is what happen :

[image]

[EDIT]

Here are my form and customcontrol properties :

1 - In high resoluion (3840x2160). Everything is ok :

[image]

2 - In low resolution (1920x1080). pictureboxes are out of the customcontrol

[image]

In both cases, the customcontrol has right dimensions. The problem comes from pictureboxes who are not located properly when screen size is 1920x1080

[EDIT]

[SOLUTION]

Edit picturebox location manually and don't trust in anhchor property lol

Comment: Remove the anchor and try manually placing your custom control to the desired location.

Comment: It doesn't works, there are very strange things that happened (see next comment)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13228185/how-to-configure-an-app-to-run-correctly-on-a-machine-with-a-high-dpi-setting-e/13228495#13228495

Comment: Thanks Hans but it doesn't works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this to the CustomControl below `InitializeComponent();` and the control will always show up in the upper right corner.

`pictureBox.Location=new Point(this.Width-(pictureBox.Width+16),0);`

> Sometimes it may also need `pictureBox.BringToFront;`
>
> Make sure to rebuild your solution and add the CustomControl(or UserControl whatever) again to get the new updated control.

Comment: Doesn't works, see my update, problem comes from pictureboxes location and not customcontrol size or location

Comment: @HugoH:        I think, if you add the same to the CustomControl, it may solve the problem. I have edited my answer. Pls try it.

Comment: Yes works when I put manually picturebox location. It was the job of the anchor property but i will set manually the location. Thank You

Comment: @HugoH         If this works, pls mark as answer for others to get help in need.

Comment: Done, Thank You @D J